# Coordinates of the Matsushima castle (松島城)?

Tags: japan, architecture, locate-this

Google Maps and Wikimapia don't know about 松島城 (Matsushima castle).

I would start to doubt its existence if it were not for the numerous pictures available:

[image: Matsushima Castle] [CC-BY-SA-3.0 Kumamushi](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Matsushimajo.JPG)

It has a view on Matsushima Bay.

What are its latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I also find it incredibly difficult to search for a lot of things in Japan, especially in English on Google.  Having the exact Japanese name and address makes things easier.

This tower is actually not a "Castle" but rather a "castle style tower".  It is an observation/look-out tower.

Here is the address:
松島城天守閣天望台
〒981-0213 Miyagi-ken, Miyagi-gun, Matsushima-machi, Matsushima, Chōnai

[image]

I don't know much about it, perhaps it is hard to find on Google because it isn't really (historically) significant... ? I did find one blog post on the internet that mentions it: https://smoloney.wordpress.com/page/3/

**edit:** [another link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jpellgen/4178549996) with some discussion on what this structure might be

Comment: Bravo, beat me to it. I had the right bay and the same blog, but hadn't gotten closer yet.

Comment: Funnily enough, Google Maps does not know the address (Chonai 115) mentioned on most places referring to it ([such](http://www.geocities.jp/matusimajyou/) [as](http://4travel.jp/domestic/area/tohoku/miyagi/matsushima/matsushima/hotplace/11287734/) [those](http://loco.yahoo.co.jp/place/g-dzb8t-A66Yk/)).

Comment: Here's a video going up to the tower.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjdu_xP3BPE  As far as I know, it is not so much a castle, as a viewing platform in the shape of a castle.